# What is the use of Thread.BeginThreadAffinity() method in Thread class?

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the use of `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()` method in Thread class ? 
It will be helpful for me to understand if you provide its sample example with exaplaination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET 1.x, a Thread was always matched with an operating system thread.  At the request of the SQL Server team, that association was broken for .NET 2.0.  A CLR host can now take control of thread mapping itself, the [IHostTaskManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164562.aspx) is the work-horse interface for that.  There's a good backgrounder in this [blog post](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/07/26/3094.aspx).

Sometimes code really does care that it runs on a particular operating system thread.  Windows critical sections and mutants would be an example.  Really, any kind of unmanaged code interop.  Thread.BeginThreadAffinity() invokes IHostTaskManager::BeginThreadAffinity() to let the host know that the task should not be allowed to run on another operating system thread but stick on the one it is currently on, until EndThreadAffinity() is called.

But, don't worry about any of this.  The SQL Server project was a bust, they couldn't get it reliable.  There have been no signs that they'll try again.

Comment: <The SQL Server project was a bust> SQLCLR isn't perfect, but it satisfies a need. Surely better than extended stored procs. Why do you think that it is so bad?

Comment: @binarycoder, no not that one.  The bust was trying to run sqlclr code on fibers.

Answer (score 4):

Did you read the remarks section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) . It explains it pretty well IMO.

> Some hosts of the common language
>   runtime, such as Microsoft SQL Server
>   2005, provide their own thread
>   management. A host that provides its
>   own thread management can move an
>   executing task from one physical
>   operating system thread to another at
>   any time. Most tasks are not affected
>   by this switching. However, some tasks
>   have thread affinity - that is, they
>   depend on the identity of a physical
>   operating system thread. These tasks
>   must inform the host when they execute
>   code that should not be switched.
>
> For example, if your application calls
>   a system API to acquire an operating
>   system lock that has thread affinity,
>   such as a Win32 CRITICAL_SECTION, you
>   must call BeginThreadAffinity before
>   acquiring the lock, and
>   EndThreadAffinity after releasing the
>   lock.